# How to Select the record with IF ELSE Condtions in mysql?

Tags: mysql

How to Select the record with IF ELSE Condtions in mysql?
I have some records in User table (please See below):
and I want to put the all recoredS of YAHOO, GMAIL, HOTMAIL in EMAIL fields if YAHOO is null then EMAIL field will take gmail or hotmail(i have mentioned in image my expected results)
[image]

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Whose idea was to split it to a different columns?

Comment: I smell a good exercise in normalization coming ...

Answer (score 5):

You want the coalesce function:

```
select id, name, coalesce(yahoo, gmail, hotmail) as email
from t
```

COALESCE returns the first non-NULL value.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id,name,
    IFNULL(yahoo,IFNULL(gmail,hotmail)) email
FROM UserTable;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply.
It will work for two colomn in the condition,
but If I have multiplecolomn like gmail, hotmail, mac, etc. then?